# why std::move takes forward_reference instead of lvaue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Just to confirm what I understood about `std::move`

`std::move` - converts `T&` to `T&&` so that the `T's` move constructor would kick in(if it exist otherwise the copy ctor will play its role unless we aren't externally deleted move ctor/assignment).

when I've looked at the possible implementation of `std::move` it's like

```
template<typename T>
typename remove_reference<T>::type&& move(T&& param)
{
using ReturnType =typename remove_reference<T>::type&&;
return static_cast<ReturnType>(param);
}
```

The reason it uses `remove_reference<T>` is because of the reference collapsing that applied over the forward_reference `T&&`

I just wonder why we need forward reference,couldn't we done that by

```
template<typename T>
T&& moveInQuestion(T& p){
  return static_cast<T&&>(p);
}

struct someType{};
someType lvalref;
static_assert(is_same<decltype(moveInQuestion(lvalref)),decltype(std::move(lvalref))>::value,"");
```

`static_assert` hasn't failed.

And I also believe that the value category that meant for `std::move` is an `lvalue` with this being the case could `moveInQuestion` possibly be better than `std::move`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual example is generic code like

```
template<class T>
T frob() {
    std::vector<T> x = /* ... */;
    return std::move(x[0]);
}
```

With your `move`, this breaks when `T` is `bool`, since in that case `x[0]` is a prvalue proxy reference rather than an lvalue.